# Determine whether element was added by JS vs original HTML doc *OR* detect when a script updates a node by InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, javascript-framework, mutation-observers

In short, I need to know if certain elements on the page are on the page because a some script inserted them via the InnerHtml property on a parent element, or whether they were part of the original HTML document that downloaded.  These two possibilities mean very different things in this (absurd) application.

### **The Actual Use Case:**

A 3rd party script updates random node elements on a page by setting the InnerHtml attribute of the element(s).  I have full control over the browser (WPF / GeckoFx / XulRunner), and the ability to inject and modify (new) JS at will, but have no insight or ability to modify the heavily obfuscated 3rd party script whatsoever.

The ONLY way to get the data I need, is to determine after page load, whether certain elements on the screen, if they exist, were loaded by the third party script (innerHtml), or if they were part of the original Html document before the 3rd party script ran.

---

Simply comparing the original html content source of the page to its final state is difficult, because there is a lot of inline scripting on the original page.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A mutation observer should do the trick I believe

Comment: @Xotic750 I couldn't get that to work.  I injected my script before any other scripts fired, and tracked all mutation events (nodeAdded type).  As the browser parses the html document, it adds new nodes to the dom.  I couldn't figure out a way to differentiate nodes that resulted from that, vs nodes that were added via innerHtml calls.  The best idea I had on that front was to disable all js, load the page, listen to the observer, and then reload with js enabled, but that looks like such a minefield of a road to aim down.

Comment: I think your script would need to be in the `head` tag of the loading page, otherwise I fear you may be out of luck.

Comment: If you can run your script after the DOM is ready and before any others, you could clone the document body and compare nodes of interest before and after. Pretty dirty though. Another idea is to overwrite the *Element* constructor with your own that replaces the *innerHTML* property with a getter/setter of your choosing that dispatches an event, then uses the original *innerHTML*. Only feasible as you have "*full control over the browser*", it will not work as a general solution. Just ideas…

Comment: Do you know what triggers the modification? A dom event? A timer? Directly on script tag execution?

Comment: @the8472 no, we have to assume it could be anything, including just direct script tag execution.  A lot of it is trying to finish before the page load completes, and a lot of it does things like load images, which in turn will delay the page load event.

Comment: @RobG that is a fantastic idea, I'm looking into it now, I'll let you know if I make any progress

Comment: @RobG scripts can execute before dom ready, so he has no guarantee that the DOM hasn't already been modified before that. That's why I asked about the timing in the first place.

Comment: @RobG you beautiful bastard.  You put me on the right path.  Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229916(v=vs.85).aspx

It turns out you can absolutely overwrite the innerHTML function, so you can mock out your own event receiver, and it works across all elements.  Its an insane hack, but it works.  Put this in an answer, and I'll select yours.  In retrospect, its so obvious.  Thank you so much.

Comment: That's a reflection on my parents! :-) (a line from a [*Shelly Berman skit*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nagzOGCc8N4)) Glad it put you on the right track. Post what you come up as an answer to your OP. This approach has been around for some time (e.g. early Prototype.js), even though it can't be recommend it as a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the suggestions to use mutation observers don't apply to this circumstance.  Mutation observers are agnostic to the reason *why* a dom node was added to the page, they only report that one was.  This means it is impossible to determine whether a piece of the DOM was added because the page is still loading, or because a script has fired and added content dynamically.

HOWEVER

This article explains how **it is possible to overwrite the InnerHTML getter/setter properties of every element in the dom**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229916(v=vs.85).aspx  Since InnerHTML is always called by javascript, it becomes trivial for me to know whether or not a certain part of the dom was loaded using this function call or not.

While that is almost certainly overkill and not a good idea for most applications, for strange situations such as this, and the building of js frameworks, it likely makes good sense.

In case that article goes offline at some point, my initial code looks similar to the following:

```
var elem = isInIE() ? HTMLElement : Element;    // IE and FF have different inheritance models, behind the scenes.
var proxiedInnerHTML = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(elem.prototype, "innerHTML");

Object.defineProperty(elem.prototype, "innerHTML", {
    set: function ( htmlContent )
    {
        // custom code goes here

        proxiedInnerHTML.set.call(this, htmlContent);
    });
```

One should be warned in older browsers, or if you use the wrong element (HTMLElement vs Element), the call will fail on the innerHTML call, not on the property definition.

*Dealing with prototypes in browsers:*

I tested this block in FF and IE, but not in Chrome.  More importantly, I found posts stating that there is no guarantee in the w3c spec that specifies how the browsers deal with inheritance of their element types, so there is no guarantee that HtmlDivElement will call the HtmlElement or Element base method for InnerHTML in future or past versions of any given browser.

That said, it is pretty simple to create a webpage with all reserved html keywords, and test whether this technique works on them or not.  For IE and FF, as of Jan 2015, this technique works across the board.

*Old Browser Support:*

Though I am not using it, in older browsers, you can use

```
document.__defineGetter__("test", /* getter function */ );
document.__defineSetter__("test", /* setter function */ );
document.__lookupGetter__("test");
document.__lookupSetter__("test");
```

Thank you to RobG for sending me down this path

Answer (score 1):

*If* the scripts rely on jQuery it's quite easy, you can just use the `$.holdReady()` to delay the firing of the ready event until after your observer is listening.

HTML:

```
<h1>Sample title</h1>
<p>Sample paragraph</p>
```

Js:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append("<p>Foo</p>").append("<p>Bar</p>");
});

(function() {
    $.holdReady(true);
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
    });
    var target = document.querySelector('html');
    var config = {
        childList: true,
        attributes: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
        observer.observe(target, config);
        $.holdReady(false);
    }, 1);
}());
```

This will work regardless of where the other scripts bind to the ready event as you can see above.

---

Needless to say however that assuming that other scripts rely on jQuery is far from something we can always count on. If we're looking for a solution that works regardless of it, we'll have to get tricky.

HTML is as was before.
Js **at the end of the body**:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append("<p>Foo</p>").append("<p>Bar</p>");
});

(function() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
    });
    var target = document.querySelector('html');
    var config = {
        childList: true,
        attributes: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true
    };
    observer.observe(target, config);
}());
```

To get the expected functionality ensure that this script block is the absolute last script block at the bottom of body. This ensures that all of the static DOM is already present and that we can start listening at the correct time.
We're assuming that all other scripts start modifying DOM after the load or ready event has fired. If this isn't the case, move the script blocks accordingly so that this script fires at the end of the DOM parsing and the other scripts fire after this one.

I haven't tested this thoroughly, but this should get you started.

Comment: This was my original idea for solving this problem.  We can't assume jQuery, (though maybe that can work x% of the time?).  The main problem then becomes that innerHTML uses the same Dom Parsing that the browser does on pageload, so the mutation observer sees them both as the same.  Which means we actually need to delay all js evaluation until after my js has run, which I have a few ideas on (load the page first with js disabled, build a browser plugin that disables all 3rd party scripts, use a proxy to delay responses from any other domain, etc), but I'm a bit scared of how hairy that all is

Answer (score 1):

A mutation observer should (mostly) work based on the following assumptions:

- the HTML parser only appends nodes along the bottom-most branches of the tree. I.e. they all should arrive in tree order. anything that doesn't is script-generated
- it's trivial to keep track of the last inserted node between mutation observer batches
- .innerHTML does not only add nodes but it also removes the current child nodes, especially the often present whitespace text nodes or comments, the html parser otoh should not generate any removals
- any mutations after the dom ready event will obviously have been performed by javascript
- if in doubt any subtree could be double-checked by comparing contents of the nearest uniquely identifiable ancestor node to a document object generated from the html source without script execution (XMLHttpRequest can return the contents in document form instead of text)
- you can also ignore any modifications done by any trusted scripts until the 3rd party script has been loaded, this should avoid at least some false positives. after that point though you obviously won't be able to tell apart which script was responsible for the modification.

So it should be possible to build a classifier for mutation events to tell script-generated and parser-generated nodes apart with good accuracy. There will be some edge-cases where you can't be sure and ways to refine it but without knowing further details I think this might be good enough.

Since you have full control over your browser you can get your own script executed as early as possible via [DOMWindowCreated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMWindowCreated) events in privileged code and/or [frame scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager#Loading_frame_scripts).